# How to block printing functionality(CTRL + P) on windows text editors?

Tags: c, winapi, dll-injection

I want to block printing functionality(CTRL + P) on windows platform for specific applications. I am doing it using keyboard hook. I am able to detect CTRL + P but I am not able to stop it. I am returning from hook procedure in case of CTRL + P but application still receives this message and process printing.

```
LRESULT __declspec(dllexport)__stdcall  CALLBACK KeyboardProc(
    int nCode,
    WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam)
{
    FILE* f1;
    static WPARAM wPrevParam;

    if (((DWORD)lParam & 0x40000000) && (HC_ACTION == nCode))
    {
        if ((wParam == VK_SPACE) || (wParam == VK_RETURN) || (wParam == VK_CONTROL) || (wParam >= 0x2f) && (wParam <= 0x100))
        {
            char ch;
            f1 = fopen("d:\\report.txt", "a+");
            if (wParam == VK_CONTROL)
            {
                if (wPrevParam == 0x50)// 0x50 = P
                {
                    const char* text = "CTRL-P detected.";
                    fwrite(text, strlen(text), 1, f1);
                    fclose(f1);
                    wParam = 0;
                    lParam = 0;
                    return 1;
                }

                const char *text = "CTRL";
                fwrite(text, strlen(text), 1, f1);
                fprintf(f1, "%02X\n", (unsigned char)wParam);
            }
            else
            {
                wPrevParam = wParam;
            }

            fclose(f1);
        }

    }

    LRESULT RetVal = CallNextHookEx(hkb, nCode, wParam, lParam);

    return  RetVal;

}
```

Comment: This really feels like the wrong solution to the problem, no matter what the problem actually is!

Comment: If you don't want people printing from **their** computers, don't give them applications to run there.  Because whatever you do, they can undo.  And you will have annoyed your customers along the way.  Because guess what?  If it displays on **their** screen, they can **always** print it.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. If you want to add the solution you've found, write it up in the form of an answer and post it in the space below intended for that purpose. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more information. It is not appropriate to edit the solution into the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to block printing functionality(CTRL + P) on windows platform
>   for specific applications. I am doing it using keyboard hook. I am
>   able to detect CTRL + P but I am not able to stop it.

This blocks [Ctrl] + "P" in a **WH_KEYBOARD_LL** hook... but won't prevent printing by [File] [Print] or other way of course... =>

```cpp
    LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        DWORD dwKey = 0;
        if (HC_ACTION == nCode)
        {
            KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *pkbdll = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
            dwKey = pkbdll->vkCode;
            BOOL bCtlDown = GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) < 0;
            if (bCtlDown && dwKey == 'P')
            {           
                Beep(6000, 10);
                return 1;
            }
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(hKeyboardHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
```

Comment: Windows application to block CTRL + P using WH_KEYBORAD_LL hook works. Updated solution in question. Thanks Castorix

Answer (score 0):

Windows application to block CTRL + P using WH_KEYBORAD_LL hook works. So working code snippet will be as follows:

```
#include<fstream>
#include<windows.h>

using namespace std;

ofstream out("logs.txt", ios::out);

LRESULT CALLBACK keyboardHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static bool controlPressed = false;
    PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT p = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)(lParam);

    if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        if (p->vkCode == VK_LCONTROL || p->vkCode == VK_RCONTROL)
        {
            controlPressed = true;
        }
        else if (char(tolower(p->vkCode)) == 'p' && true == controlPressed)
        {
            out << "<CONTROL + P Detected>";
                return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            controlPressed = false;
        }

    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    HHOOK keyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL,
        keyboardHookProc,
        hInstance,
        0
    );

    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Press OK to stop blocking of printing."), TEXT("Information"), MB_OK);
    out.close();
    return 0;
}
```